# Invalid Content Type when calling a POST api from azure logic app

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-logic-apps

[image]I have created a Web API using .net core to POST file (excel).

When attaching the file from the post man it is working as expected but now I am trying to do the same using Azure logic app.

I am using a FTP connector and reading the file from it and then calling the REST api, the end point is getting hit but however I am unable to get the file data.

I am very much new to logic apps and tried to find a lot but no luck.

Web API

```
[HttpPost("x")]
public async Task<IActionResult> MigrateHistoricalData()
{
    int filesCount = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files.Count;
    if (filesCount > 0)
    {
        var file = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files[0];
        if (file != null && file.Length > 0)
        {
            // other logic
        }
     }
    else
    {
         return new BadRequestObjectResult("No files found in the request.");
    }

   return null;
}
```

Error Image:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could update your browser to the latest version and have a try.

It's a MVC [bug](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5631), and on 13th of September 2018 Microsoft has implemented [a fix](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/commit/d0ddb068bea92f75fa0c783e97065ecbe3b2e04c) for this issue, and it will be **released with in ASP.NET Core 2.2**.

Answer (score 0):

Set content-type of the HTTP request header to multipart/form-data in the Logic App and see if that helps [Logic App Http Connector Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHNcD.png)